DBT Seed File For Prod/QA/Dev
I have seed files based on environment, schema name are same though out environment. But content of file changes.
I have written two macro to handle schema_name and generate_alias_name as below in image
    {% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}

    {%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}
    {%- if custom_schema_name is none -%}

        {{ default_schema }}

    {%- else -%}

        {{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

    {%- endif -%}
{% endmacro %}

Another One
{% macro generate_alias_name(custom_alias_name=none, node=none) -%}
  {%- set tgt = target.schema -%}
  {{ log("Without namespace: " ~ node, info=True) }}
  {% set env_methods = ["sandbox", "staging", "prod"] %}
    {%- if custom_alias_name is none -%}
        {%- if node.resource_type == 'seed' -%}
            {%- if node.name.startswith('sandbox_') -%}
                {{ node.name[node.name.find('sandbox_') + 8 : node.name|length] }}
            {%- elif node.name.startswith('prod_') -%}
                {{ node.name[node.name.find('prod_') + 5 : node.name|length] }}
            {%- elif node.name.startswith('staging_') -%}
                {{ node.name[node.name.find('staging_') + 8 : node.name|length] }}
            {%- else -%}
                {{ node.name }}
           {%- endif -%}
        {%- else -%}
            {{ node.name }}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- else -%}
        {{ custom_alias_name | trim }}
    {%- endif -%}

{%- endmacro %}

Folder Structure (show only for seed)
Project
|-seed
|--staging
|--staging_etl_control_table.csv
|--staging_reload_status.csv
|--sandbox
|--sandbox_etl_control_table.csv
|--sandbox_reload_status.csv
|--prod
|--prod_etl_control_table.csv
|--prod_reload_status.csv
enter image description here
I have tried to overwrite macro in seed.sql to filter recored based on environment date insert. But it didn't work.
Also, little bit work do macro handling for generate_alias_name. But it din't work
